# c# get index for insertion of an item to the list which is ordered descending order

Tags: c#

I am having trouble putting my list in descending order when new items are being inserted. I also want to get index. My code is as follows:

```
int index;
if (mylist.Count == 0) {
  mylist.Add(item);
  index = 0;
  return;
}
for (int i = 0; i < mylist.Count; i++) {
  if (item < mylist[i]) {
    index = i;
    mylist.Insert(i, item);
    return;
  }
}
index = mylist.Count - 1;
mylist.Add(item);
```

Is there an easier way of doing this?

It's not pretty as a code. I bet there is a better way.

Comment: Have you considered using the right tool for the job? There's a [`SortedList<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2?view=net-8.0) class that makes sure it stays sorted appropriately.

Comment: And even without using that, `List<T>` supports a `BinarySearch` method to find the appropriate insertion point in log time rather than your linear search

Comment: In sorted list, can I get the index of newlu added object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq to simplify code:

```cs
var index = myList.TakeWhile(listItem => listItem < item).Count();
myList.Insert(item, index);
```

BTW, `Insert` will work as `Add` if `index` = `List.Count`.

Another point: you wrote that you want to insert in descending order, while actually your code inserts in ascending order (it inserts new item before one that is greater than inserted item).

My code as well inserts item in ascending order. If you really want descending order change condition to: `TakeWhile(listItem => item < listItem)`

Comment: Thank you for the help. I noticed that now.

Answer (score 0):

[`IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.indexof?view=net-8.0) can be used to find the index

```cs
var index = myList.IndexOf(listItem => listItem >= item);
if (index < 0)  // not found
    myList.Add(item);
else
    myList.Insert(item, index);
```

But given that the list will be sorted, `BinarySearch` might be better

```cs
var comparer = Comparer.Create((a, b) => b.CompareTo(a));  // reverse comparer
var index = myList.BinarySearch(item, comparer);
```